# Failed to import jsoup library in android studio?

Tags: android, gradle, jsoup, android-studio, build.gradle

I was trying to integrate j soup library in android studio. I am getting error.

StackTrace:

```
  Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'JsoupProject'.
```

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   Main Manifest missing from C:\Users\Asthme\Androidstudio\JsoupProject\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

settings .gradle:

```
    include ':Jsoup'
        include ':libraries:jsoup-1.7.2.jar'
```

Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
}
   }
    apply plugin: 'android'


      dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'jsoup-1.7.2.jar')
      }

       repositories {
           mavenCentral()
          }

        android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
  }

       dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

   }
```

Library build.gradle

```
   buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
}
    }

     apply plugin: 'android-library'
    android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
  }
```

Comment: Try just using `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`  No need to specify the exact file name. that would be annoying every time you change file names / add new jar files. In settings.gradle you shouldn't need to add anything related to jsoup

Comment: @dymmeh changed and ran,not working

Comment: Please remove the jar-file from your `settings.gradle`, like Scott Barta posted it in his answer. Additionally you could try `compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.2.jar')`.

Answer (score 26):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
}
```

(check the latest version number here: https://jsoup.org/download)

Answer (score 5):

Don't include the Jsoup library from your `settings.gradle`, that's only for module. Just put it in the `dependencies` statement from any module that needs it. I see you've done it in your `build.gradle` file in your question, so you should be fine there.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was: Copy for /app/libs the jsoup-1.10.3.jar, after import in the MainActivity.java `"import org.jsoup.Jsoup;"` and it working. With the code `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` in the buil.gradle(app) it work. [jsoup in the /app/libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KiyQ.jpg) [build.gradle(app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Pv9.jpg)

Note: I am using Android Studio 2.2.1

Comment: i think op wants to use gradle