# Unable to import jsoup in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I keep getting the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'jsoup'` when I try to do an import, but I already have the `Implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'` in `build.graddle (:app)` as a dependency

The import that I have is `import org.jsoup.*;`

I should mention that I have looked at [Failed to import jsoup library in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331570/failed-to-import-jsoup-library-in-android-studio)

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have Jsoup installed?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that I needed to manually sync the gradle file. If you are having the same problem you can manually sync it by hovering over `Implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'` and click on the yellow light bulb on the side of android studio.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I have been messing around with this way too long trying to figure this out.